# Polars - Unstack dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to do the following operation

Input data:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "left": ["One", "One", "One", "One", "Two"],
    "center": ["P", "P", "I", "I", "I"],
    "right": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
})
```

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬────────┬───────┐
│ left ┆ center ┆ right │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ One  ┆ P      ┆ 100   │
│ One  ┆ P      ┆ 100   │
│ One  ┆ I      ┆ 100   │
│ One  ┆ I      ┆ 100   │
│ Two  ┆ I      ┆ 100   │
└──────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Expected output:

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ left ┆ P   ┆ I   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ One  ┆ 200 ┆ 200 │
│ Two  ┆ 0   ┆ 100 │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In pandas we use

```py
df.groupby(["left", "center"])["right"]
            .sum()
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
```

However, i am unable to replicate this in polars? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, another way would be to use `.pivot_table()`

In Polars, it is called [`.pivot()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot)

```py
df.pivot(index='left', columns='center', values='right', aggregate_function='sum')
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ left ┆ P    ┆ I   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ One  ┆ 200  ┆ 200 │
│ Two  ┆ null ┆ 100 │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

You can then `.fill_null(0)`